# Как уменьшить рекурсивно картинки в каталоге в Linux centos7?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, resize

есть папка, в ней лежит много папок с картинками, задача в том что бы уменьшить картинки в папках, просто заменить старую версию новой с сохранением имени.

Нашел команду
`for i in` ls`; do convert -resize '1200x' -quality 85 $i $i; done`

Она отлично работает для одной папки, как пройтись этой командой по всем папкам?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да при этом очень желательно, что бы если картинка и так нужного размера, то она не обрабатывалась бы, что бы не тратить на нее время

Comment: Чтобы сжимались только широкие картинки, достаточно указать `convert -resize '1200>' ...`. Вторая мысль: вы хотите заменить исходные файлы сжатыми. Тогда лучше пользоваться командой `mogrify` - эта команда переписывает исходный файл.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! зашел в каталог с папками,  ввел find . -exec grep mogrify -resize '1200>' '1200x' -quality 85 {} {} \; пишет что неправильная опция у грепа -t, смотрите помощь, Что ему не так, вроде бы нет такой опции...

Answer (score 2):

Где то так

```
find . -exec convert -resize '1200x' -quality 85 {} {} \;
```

если известно, что это jpg картинки, то можно улучшить, добавив -name "*.jpg".

Но будьте осторожны!

Comment: `find . -name '*.jpg' -exec ...` чтобы находить только JPG файлы.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но что то не заработало... С учетом всех комментариев составил такую конструкцию : find . -name '*.png' -exec grep mogrify -resize '1200>' '1200x' -quality 85 {} {} \; Пишет Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Comment: Я не знаю как туда попал grep

Comment: `find . -name '*.png' -exec mogrify -verbose -resize '1200>' -quality 85 '{}' ';'`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! find . -name '*.png' -exec mogrify -verbose -resize '1200>' -quality 85 '{}' ';' заработало!